# Strange behavior reading files in Java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read nearly 120,000 lines from a file, put the data into a new record, and add this record to a list.

My problem is that I can't load all the data getting weird behavior.
In particular, using BufferedReader a first time I can count the rows and the result is correct, but when I try with a while loop to load the data into memory I see that the loop iterates about 60,000 times and the final list with the data contains only about 5000 objects.

I've also tried using other classes for loading data, but I always get the same problem.

I am currently using java 17 with spring and javafx.

Thank you.

I am attaching the latest version of my method:

```
public void getFixList(FixReadyCallback callback) {
    List<Fix> fixList;
    int firstCount = 0;
    int whileCount = 0;

    try {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/fligh_data/fix.dat");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));

        String currentLine = null;

        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            firstCount++;
        }
        fixList = new ArrayList<>(firstCount);

        reader.close();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            whileCount++;
            currentLine = reader.readLine();

            if (currentLine.matches(
                    "[-]?[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{6}\\s+[-]?[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{6}\\s+[0-9A-Z]{2,5}")) {
                String[] splitted = currentLine.split("\\s+");

                String denomination = splitted[2];
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(splitted[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(splitted[1]);
                Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);

                fixList.add(new Fix(denomination, coordinates));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("FIRST_COUNT -> " + firstCount);
        System.out.println("WHILE_COUNT -> " + whileCount);
        System.out.println("LIST_SIZE -> " + fixList.size());

        reader.close();
        callback.onReady(fixList);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the output of the terminal:

```
FIRST_COUNT -> 119724
WHILE_COUNT -> 59862
LIST_SIZE -> 5128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  whileCount++;
  currentLine = reader.readLine();
  ...
}
```

This *skips every other line in your file*.  `currentLine` is *already* the next line in the file, and then you overwrite it with the line after that.  I think you only meant to read one line per loop.

It seems pretty clear that you should simply delete the last line I quoted:

```
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  whileCount++;
  ...
}
```